# Subversion server on ubuntu with mutiple repositories and checkout problem

Tags: ubuntu, subversion

I have 3 customers, `FirmA`, `FirmB` and `FirmC`. Under directory `/srv` I've created three subdirectories, `FirmA`, `FirmB` and `FirmC` that will act as a svn root for every firm. Inside svn root directories I've created for `FirmA` three repositories (one for each project), for `FirmB` five repositories (one for each project) and 2 for the `FirmC` (one for each project) via `svnadmin create` command. Every firm has access to its own subversion root directory only. Now, how do I configure `svnserve` in a fashion that `FirmA` access its projects via port 3690, `FirmB` via 3692 and `FirmC` via port 3692? Can I run `svnserve` multiple times with different port parameters and how do I configure them to run at boot? I am using `Ubuntu Server 14.10`.

And the final question: I've checked out `project1` (with full path `/srv/svn_firmA/project1` into my workstation under `test` directory and checkout is ok, but in `test` directory I get whole dir structure (the source resided inside `/home/user/working_copy_firmA_project1/test/srv/svn_firmA/project1` instead of `/home/user/working_copy_firmA_project1`. Why?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to run 3 instances of svnserve with at least different `-r` and `--listen-port` parameters
2. It's impossible for checkout to build such long tree, except if such destination was specified by hand (or if `/srv` is real repository-root) in `svn co`

> If PATH is omitted, the basename of the URL will be used as the destination.

Thus:

```
cd /home/user/working_copy_firmA_project1/test
svn co /srv/svn_firmA/project1
```

must to add only `project1` subdir immediatelly to `test`